# How to restrict an iterator to being a forward iterator?

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

I have a function that needs to enumerate an iterator multiple times, but [according to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28f7db1d.aspx), *"Once you increment any copy of an input iterator, none of the other copies can safely be compared, dereferenced, or incremented thereafter."*

So to make things easier, instead of creating a separate implementation for non-forward-iterators that copies the data and enumerates the copy, I want to restrict my method to only taking in forward iterators, and rejecting input iterators statically.

Right now I have something like:

```
template<typename It, typename TCallback /*signature: bool(value_type)*/>
bool EnumerateTwice(const It &begin, const It &end, TCallback callback)
{
    for (It it = begin; it != end; ++it)
        if (!callback(*it))
            return false;
    for (It it = begin; it != end; ++it)
        if (!callback(*it))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

but nothing restricts `It` to being a forward iterator.

How do I place that restriction on the templated function? (C++03)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use SFINAE and replace `bool` by:

```
typename enable_if<
   is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<It>::iterator_category,
           std::forward_iterator_tag>::value,
   bool>::type
```

You may need to define `is_same` and `enable_if` yourself if you don't want to pull them from Boost or TR1:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
struct is_same { static const bool value = false; };

template <typename T>
struct is_same<T, T> { static const bool value = true; };

template <bool, typename> struct enable_if { };
template <typename T> struct enable_if<true, T> { typedef T type; };
```

Comment: +1 Oooooo didn't know iterators are tagged! That's pretty handy. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: This will reject bidirectional and random-access iterators. Use `is_base_of` instead of `is_same` for proper semantics.

Comment: @ildjarn: indeed, but the OP said he wanted a Forward Iterator only. I trust he can compose bools for other conditions, or indeed use inheritance as you suggest.

Comment: @Kerrek : The OP said he wants to reject input iterators statically, not limit the iterators to only forward iterators (that would be silly). Standard iterator tags already use inheritance for this exact reason -- `forward_iterator_tag` inherits from `input_iterator_tag`, `bidirectional_iterator_tag` inherits from `forward_iterator_tag`, `random_access_iterator_tag` inherits from `bidirectional_iterator_tag`.

Comment: (To clarify, a bidirectional iterator _is-a_ forward iterator and a random-access iterator _is-a_ bidirectional iterator, so restricting iterators to forward iterators should include bidirectional and random-access iterators. Meanwhile, a forward iterator _is-an_ input iterator, but the reverse is not true. The iterator tag inheritance hierarchy already reflects, and has always reflected, these relationships.)

Answer (score 4):

Not tested but you could try something along the lines of:

```
template<typename It, typename TCallback /*signature: bool(value_type)*/>
bool EnumerateTwice_Interal(const It &begin, const It &end, TCallback callback, 
      std::forward_iterator_tag)
{
     //do your things
}

template<typename It, typename TCallback /*signature: bool(value_type)*/>
bool EnumerateTwice(const It &begin, const It &end, TCallback callback)
{
    EnumerateTwice_Internal(begin, end, callback,
        typename std::iterator_traits<It>::iterator_category());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using `std::enable_if`:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename It, typename TCallback>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<std::forward_iterator_tag,
                        typename std::iterator_traits<It>::iterator_category>::value,
                    bool>::type
EnumerateTwice(It begin, It end, TCallback) {
    ...
}
```

This uses class from C++11 but all of this can be done in C++03 as well.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on rodrigo's answer -- I found this solution, and thought it's worth mentioning:

```
struct True { unsigned char _[2]; operator bool() const { return true; } };
char is_forward_iterator(std::input_iterator_tag const *) { return 0; }
True is_forward_iterator(std::forward_iterator_tag const *) { return True(); }
```

Now, if you want to check it inside some function, you can say:

```
if (is_forward_iterator(static_cast<iterator_traits<It>::iterator_category*>(0)))
{
    ...
}
```

and if you want to check it within templates, you can check for:

```
sizeof(
  is_forward_iterator(static_cast<iterator_traits<It>::iterator_category*>(0))
) > 1
```

with the primary advantage of this method being that it avoids declaring templates (e.g. for better compilation speed).